# Android /d folder

Tags: root-access, file-system, file-management, system, android-versions

On all of my devices there's a folder called /d on two of my devices it's full of folders, on the other it's empty. What is the /d folder? What is it for? And why is it empty on one device?

Comment: I have the same, and it has a 'shortcut' link over the icon. It's filled with > 2000 items and has a value of 0.0 bytes of memory taken up. I'm absolutely lost what this does.

Comment: @RossC I know I've searched the web high and low and there's just nothing, being a stock android folder one would think there'd be some info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you type on a terminal console:

```
ls -l /d 
lrwxrwxrwx root root    2013-01-01 01:00 d -> /sys/kernel/debug/
```

meaning /d is a symlink to that other folder, probably there for compatibility with old versions.

So now the question is: what is /sys/kernel/debug/?
That folder is used to mount debugfs filesystem and it's used, as the name suggests, to debug kernel.
Kernel must be compiled with CONFIG_DEBUG_FS option set to yes, so that's maybe the reason why some phones have files in it and some don't.

One important thing to note is that debugfs is a RAM based filesystem, so AFAIK it's using RAM space not disk space.

More info http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugfs

Comment: Thanks a million, this was driving me mad. Knew it says was a symlink but nothing beyond that!